# OnTriggerEnter2D collision.gameObject.tag Not Working & I've Setted Up Components & Written Correct Code Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I have an `OnTriggerEnter2D` function and I used `collision.gameObject.tag` and set it to the tag "Bound" without quotes, but it can't detect the tag Bound.
All of the boundaries with the tag Bound has Box Collider 2D, and the player object has Box Collider 2D. I checked "Is Trigger" without quotes for every single Box Collider 2D, and I added a Rigidbody 2D to the player object and set the gravity scale to 0. The Rigidbody 2D is Dynamic and Non-Kinematic.
Here is my code for the player (Player.cs):

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
      if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Bound") {
           SceneManager.LoadScene("DeathScreen"); //I have a scene named DeathScreen
      }
 }
```

And not only that, but that also applies to obstacles, and their tag is "Obstacle" instead.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing debug messages?

Comment: Draco18s, I haven't tried printing debug messages, and I really don't need them.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect Non-Kinematic look like NonKinematic.

Comment: A debug message could tell you *if the function is being called at all*

Comment: Let's see if there's something wrong with the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function or `SceneManager.LoadScene(...)`.

Comment: Draco18s, I tried using debug messages. I wrote `print("working?");`, and I don't see anything come up at the console.

Comment: INSIDE the if-statement or OUTSIDE? You should put it OUTSIDE and `print(collision.gameObject.tag)`, if it doesn't run: then Unity doesn't think a collision occurred (one possible problem) if it does you have information to diagnose a second possible problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone I know which is not a StackExchange member found the answer! Neither the `OnTriggerEnter2D` was making the problem nor `SceneManager.LoadScene(...)`.

I hadn't checked Simulated which was making the problem. But anyways, thanks for your answers!

Regards,

The Asker